# Ansible: ansible_user in inventory vs remote_user in playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am trying to run an Ansible playbook against a server using an account other than the one I am logged on the control machine. I tried to specify an `ansible_user` in the inventory file according to the documentation on [Inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html):

```
[srv1]
192.168.1.146 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=user1
```

However Ansible called with `ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml -vvvv` prints the following:

```
GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
<192.168.1.146> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: techraf
```

What worked for me was adding the `remote_user` argument to the playbook:

```
- hosts: srv1
  remote_user: user1
```

Now the same Ansible command connects as `user1`:

```
GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
<192.168.1.146> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: user1
```

Also adding `remote_user` variable to `ansible.cfg` makes Ansible use the intended user instead of the logged-on one.

Are the `ansible_user` in inventory file and `remote_user` in playbook/`ansible.cfg` for different purposes?

What is the `ansible_user` used for? Or why doesn't Ansible observe the setting in the inventory?

Comment: Related: [How to set a default ssh user for all hosts in Ansible?](https://superuser.com/q/1081609/87805)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're likely running into a common issue: the published ansible docs are for the development version (2.0 right now), and we don't keep the old ones around. It's a big point of contention... Assuming you're using something pre-2.0, the inventory var name you need is `ansible_ssh_user`. `ansible_user` works in 2.0 (as does `ansible_ssh_user`- it gets aliased in).

Comment: Changing `ansible_user ` to `ansible_ssh_user` worked for me with ansible 1.9.4.

Answer (score 7):

I usually add my remote username in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` as follows:

```
remote_user = MY_REMOTE_USERNAME
```

This way it is not required to configure ansible_user in the inventory file for each host entry.